# Is there any benefit to collecting treasure in Return to Castle Wolfenstein?

Tags: return-to-castle-wolfenstein

I remember in the original *Wolfenstein 3D* treasure counted towards your score, as did kills, and at certain amounts you could get an extra life. Since Doom, the idea of "lives" in id games has gone the way of the dodo.

In the "reimagined" *Return to Castle Wolfenstein* they have carried over some elements, perhaps for nostalgia's sake. Playing through the first couple of missions, I cannot see any gameplay benefit yet to collecting treasures in RtCW since there is no longer any score or lives to be had. Is it just for bragging rights, then? (The game is far too old to have achievements.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there's no benefit to gathering treasures, besides that warm fuzzy feeling you get when you find all the secrets in the game.

There are [some secret areas](http://www.planetwolfenstein.com/sp/secrets/) that contain weapons and/or ammo, but the "treasure" you find doesn't seem to effect the outcome of the game in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Too bad, because that means this bit of "nostalgia" has regressed as it used to be worth something useful beyond warm fuzzies. :)

Comment: @SeanHanley - The ports of RTCW on the ps2 and xbox had rewards for treasures (as well as some bonus prequel maps)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that when you collect the treasures and visit the secret areas, they may be exchanged for bonuses at the end of a significant level. The bonuses include extra ammo, protections, health points, etc. But they are a little expensive, and may be used only a limited number of times.